# using prepareForSegue to get a tag / id from a label

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I have a set of UILabel's and would like to put the id of the selected item into the tag. Like so:

```
UILabel *miII = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(530, 0, 25, 25)];
miII.tag=item.id;
```

I have the following where I am able to set the itemId property of the destinationViewController. The problem I am having is how do I access the tag from the UILabel? Or is there a better way to do this? I have included my experiences in comments and am not using a UITableView.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);
    ItemDetailViewController *myVC = [segue destinationViewController];

    //[myVC setItemId:12]; //  <-- hard-coding this works
    [myVC setItemId:sender.view.tag];   // this doesn't work

}

- (void)tapRecognized:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"that tap was recognized with %d", sender.view.tag); // <-- this works
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"ItemSegue" sender: self];


}
```

thx in advance

Comment: It looks like you create a label programmatically.  I don't see any information as to whether or not you store this tag in an array that is accessible class-wide.

Comment: Are you sure that `sender`is your label???

Comment: figured out answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sol'n was fairly simple but a bit cryptic based upon other q's and a's. I did the following:

```
@interface ListViewController ()
{
@private

int _itemId;
}

.....


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", segue.identifier);
    // NSLog(@"prepareForSegue: %@", sender);

    ItemDetailViewController *myVC = [segue destinationViewController];
    [myVC setItemId:_itemId];  // obviously need property for itemId on ItemDetailViewController

}

- (void)tapRecognized:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"that tap was recognized with %d", [(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender view].tag);
    _itemId=[(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender view].tag;
```

in ItemDetailiViewController.h ...

```
@interface ItemDetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) int itemId;
```